# How to show an operator is positive with positive cone.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

We are given an operator $G_\lambda:L^2((0,a^*)\times\Omega)\to L^2((0,a^*)\times\Omega)$ for $\lambda\in \mathbb{R}$ by,
$$G_\lambda(\phi(a,x))=\int_{0}^{a*}\beta(a,x)e^{-\lambda a} F(0,a)\phi(a,x)da,\hspace{0.2cm} \forall \phi \in L^2(\Omega)$$
where $F(0,a)=e^{-\int_{0}^{a}\mu(\sigma)d\sigma}$. Here both $\beta$ and $\mu$ are positive and $\Omega$ is bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}$. It is given that the operator $G_\lambda$ is positive operator in $L^2(\Omega)$ with positive cone
$L^2_+(\Omega)$ which consists of non-negative functions in $L^2(\Omega)$. Can somebody please help me in understanding

1.) What is meaning by positive cone?

2.) How to show above operator is positive operator in $L^2(\Omega)$ with positive cone $L^2_+(\Omega)$ which consists of non-negative functions in $L^2(\Omega)$}.

Comment: Are you sure there's no typo in your question? As stated, you could just pull $\phi(x)$ out of the integral.

Comment: @MaoWao Although that would be fine, but still now I have edited my expression for $G_\lambda$.